# Is there a way to tell if the user has been touching the screen in react native?

Tags: react-native

I don't see any built in method that can tell you if the user has touched the screen recently in react native. Is there anyway you can keep track of how long it's been since the user has touched the screen.

Answer (score 2):

PanResponder

```js
this._panResponder = PanResponder.create({
            onMoveShouldSetResponderCapture: () => true,
            onMoveShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,

            // Initially, set the Y position offset when touch start
            onPanResponderGrant: (e, gestureState) => {
                this.setState({
                    offset: e.nativeEvent.pageY,
                    isDividerClicked: true
                })
            },

            // When we drag the divider, set the bottomHeight (component state) again.
            onPanResponderMove: (e, gestureState) => {

                this.setState({
                    bottomHeight    : gestureState.moveY > (this.state.deviceHeight - 40) ? 40 : this.state.deviceHeight - gestureState.moveY,
                    offset: e.nativeEvent.pageY
                })
            },

            onPanResponderRelease: (e, gestureState) => {
                // Do something here for the touch end event
                this.setState({
                    offset: e.nativeEvent.pageY,
                    isDividerClicked: false
                })
            }
        });
```

Comment: So basically onPanResponderMove just tells you when someone clicks the screen. Is there any significance to the setState that I should try and keep in mind or is that just not relevant?

Comment: What do you mean?